# convert powershell Psobject to New-object

Tags: powershell, psobject

I have made a function that returns a **custom psobject**, but when I am trying to use the "**.**" to get the properties of the object noting happens, also the pipe isnt working in this type of object.

There is a way to convert this object to the one that is created with the cmdlet New-object?

Why the new psobject have missing features?

```
$ObjectProperties = @{                   
    Users     = "admin"
    Computer  = "localhost"
    Error     = $false
}
$Objects += New-Object psobject -Property $ObjectProperties

# I am trying to use select this object like $objects.computer but doesnt work
$Objects.

$objectTest = New-Object Object
$objectTest | Add-Member NoteProperty error $false
$objectTest | Add-Member NoteProperty Computadores "localhost"
$objectTest | Add-Member NoteProperty Usuarios "admin"

#I need an object like this that can be easy managed 
$objectTest
```

I have tried converting it in this way but doesn't work

```
$objectCompu = $objects |select computer|Out-String
$objectError = $Objects |select error|Out-String
$objectUsers = $Objects |select users |Out-String

$objectTest = New-Object Object
$objectTest | Add-Member NoteProperty error $objectError
$objectTest | Add-Member NoteProperty Computadores $objectCompu
$objectTest | Add-Member NoteProperty Usuarios $objectUsers
$objectTest
```

Comment: Is it because you used `$Objects +=` instead of `$Objects =` ?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler thank it worked :)

Comment: @JPBlanc ok it's an answer.

Comment: Nice. @kimo pryvt if if the answer put the question as answered please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(My comment as an answer)

`$Object += __` is short for `$Objects = $Objects + __`;

So this line:

```
$Objects += New-Object psobject -Property $ObjectProperties
```

is expecting `$Objects` to be a list, and then add an item to the list. You haven't said whether it should be a list or not, so I guess you just want to make one object, and should use `=` instead of `+=`:

```
$Objects = New-Object psobject -Property $ObjectProperties
```

Then you can do:

```
$Objects.Computer
```